# Snipped Tails - Find all table tails with missing null values

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I have really wide and deep Google BigQuery tables. Some of these tables have newly added and renamed columns, thus the new data is not appended into the old columns. This results in many tables with the new >01-01-2019 timestamped data having NULLs in some columns. I am trying to get a list of all column names that are empty as well as their table names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Google BigQuery.

Comment: You can get column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but it will not tell you which is completely NULL. You will have to scan the table and count the NULL/non-null value to discover this.

Comment: You have `pandas` tagged, so I think python might be your best bet here.  Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA, then build queries for each column to select distinct values.  You can then inspect each result set for each column in a programmatic way.